# Is it possible to extend and add secondary "All Day" row on fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am working with fullcalendar.js and have been search and digging for a way to extend the calendar by adding a secondary row that functions exactly like the All Day row, but with a different title. Is this currently possible or is the ability to extend a calendar limited?

Comment: It's limited in a way that you can't create a plugin or change an option to make this work. You can however, dig in the library itself and make your required changes. This is not recommended but sometimes when you need something custom this is the way to go.